# Pandas - search for strings inside of DataFrame cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to search a DataFrame just like I'd search a txt file: I want to scan thru it and look for occurrences of a word, and if that word appears I want to capture the number that follows it.

Here is `fish_frame`:

```
fish_frame:                   0           1           2  ASK            TRADE_DATE
0          Species       Price      Weight    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
1          GBW Cod         .55       8,059    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
2      GBE Haddock         .03      14,628    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
3      GBW Haddock         .02      87,451    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
4            GB YT        1.50       1,818    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
5            Witch        1.25       1,414    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
6        GB Winter         .40      23,757    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
7          Redfish         .02         123    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
8       White Hake         .40         934    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
9          Pollock         .02       7,900    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
10  Package Price:         NaN  $21,151.67    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
11         Species      Weight        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
12         GBE Cod         820        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
13         GBW Cod      15,279        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
14     GBE Haddock      32,250        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
15     GBW Haddock     192,793        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
16           GB YT       6,239        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
17          SNE YT       2,018        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
18          GOM YT       1,511        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
19          Plaice       2,944        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
20           Witch       1,100        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
21       GB Winter     158,608        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
22      White Hake          31        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
23         Pollock       1,983        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
24      SNE Winter       7,257        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00   
25           Price  $58,500.00        None    1  2013-06-21 14:07:00
```

So with my DataFrame, I want to look for any occurrence of the word `Price` and if it appears, then capture the number that follows it. Like on lines `10` and `25`.

I tried simple commands such as `if 'Price' in row: do this` but those didn't work since a DataFrame clearly isn't a txt file. So I tried experimenting with :

```
for row in fish_frame.iterrows():
    fish_frame.str.split('Price')
    print("fish_frame_split:", fish_frame)
```

after reading this snippet of code directly from the Pandas website (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html).:

```
In [15]: s2 = pd.Series(['a_b_c', 'c_d_e', np.nan, 'f_g_h'])

In [16]: s2.str.split('_')
Out[16]: 
0    [a, b, c]
1    [c, d, e]
2          NaN
3    [f, g, h]
dtype: object
```

But it resulted in an error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`

So all in all I'm confused about why that command fails for me, how to match the word `Price` in my DataFrame, and then how to append the number that follows `Price` to all its corresponding Fish-Weight pairs.

This is as simplified as I could make it, I think, so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
fish_frame[fish_frame[0].str.contains('Price')][1]
```

Comment: That produced: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Species'`. But so just as a side note, idk if I made this clear, row `[0]` with the titles `Species`, `Price`, etc does not contain rows that I named, those are the titles taken directly from the data table that I parsed all this data from.

Comment: Just output `fish_frame.columns` or replace `Species` and `Price` with respective headers.

Comment: I edited in the actual headers for `fish_frame`. Also, doing `print("fish_frame2:", fish_frame.columns)` produced about a 40 line error message. In none of the error message though does it point to a specific line the error occurred on....it just ends with: `KeyError: 'Species'`. I do see what you're trying to do though, I think, you're trying to look through `Species` and see if `Price` occurs in it, and if it does then append it to Price column...

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean by just outputting `fish_frame.columns`. Just print that bit? Also, that `].1` bit of code is producing a `syntax error`

Comment: Ohhh ok sorry. I did that and got: `Index([                 0,                  1,                  2,
                    'ASK',       'TRADE_DATE',    'TRADE_OR_SWAP',
                    'BID',         'TRADE_ID', 'ADVERTISED_PRICE'],
      dtype='object'`. I left out everything after `trade_date` because they're all empty

Comment: Nothing happened to the DataFrame :(

Comment: I added that line of code in, then followed it with `print("fish_frame2:", fish_frame)` and it printed an identical printout as the one above.

Comment: i think u r new to pandas if just run single line u ill get the output.

Comment: So did u get the output?

Comment: Output for `fish_frame`? Yes, I got the same exact DataFrame as the one I posted in my original question

Comment: no output for code above which i posted? what editor r u using ?

Comment: Umm I don't know.... when I open Python I just go to File-New File and then type out my code there and then hit F5 to run it in the terminal

Comment: put the above code in print statement and run the file.

Comment: OHHHHHHH that's what you meant, god I'm so dumb, sorry sorry. That produced: `10           NaN
25    $58,500.00
40    $57,750.00`

Comment: so that's u r output first is index number and second is its value. So is it right.

Comment: Awesome! I don't want to keep asking you so many questions, but do you know how to append those prices to their correct corresponding rows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148087/discussion-between-shivsn-and-theprowler).